# does Stack Overflow developers have a plan of cleaning up questions

Tags: discussion

I think are many questions with solid answers from solid users with no accepted, sometimes even no upvoted, answers. I myself am a starter in the programming business and generally give no real good answers. I mostly gain reputation from my average answers, but not the good ones I recently had a deep work. As I observed, new users tend to ask a question and wait for the actual code that solves their problem and get out without no accepting. Does Stack Overlow developer team have a plan of cleaning these questions or send warnings to these users about the subject? Or should they?

Comment: Have you found any specific examples of such questions that you can post here? I know that it's difficult to post good answers as well, since many of the easy questions on Stack Overflow have already been answered.

Comment: just click on unanswered and go to earlier pages, you'll find plenty. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238898/how-to-get-correctly-encoded-html-from-the-clipboard

Answer (score 1):

> Does Stack Overlow developer team have a plan of cleaning these questions?

No, I don't think SO. The accepted mark only defines what answer solved the **OP's** problem ( 1 person ) while useful answer should always stick on the top anyway.

> Or send warnings to these users about the subject?

I theoretically support the motion, but spamming via email is really not SO style and I wouldn't agree to it in any form.

If you mean within the website: there was a *thing* called accept rate that showed the user accept rate on each question in order to spur new users to accept answers before asking new question. [But the feature was *recently* removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate).